# ehcache cache hit performance

Tags: hibernate, ehcache, second-level-cache

Does anyone have any information on the cache hit performance of Ehcache? I'm looking for a low latency solution to data access.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can benchmark the hit ratio performance of Ehcache, but this kind of benchmark will highly depend on your code and your application, try looking at this benchmark, might help you figure out relative performance of retrieving objects from cache

http://gregluck.com/blog/archives/2010/03/comparing-memcache-and-ehcache-server-performance/